# Set JSON value default in MagicSuggest while page loading

Tags: jquery, json, magicsuggest

Set JSON value default in MagicSuggest while page loading.

Html code:

```
 <div id="ms-ajaxConfig"></div>
```

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var tags = $('#ms-ajaxConfig').magicSuggest({
        data : [{
        "id" : "255",
        "name" : "charles"
    }, {
        "id" : "261",
        "name" : "rahman"
    }, {
        "id" : "274",
        "name" : "siva"
    }]


    }); 

});
```

Expected result :

While page loading, all username must to display in mageic suggest box.

Error result :

All user name displayed in dropdown list.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the setValue([array] ids) method passing in the values you want displayed.

```
var tags = $('#ms-ajaxConfig').magicSuggest({
     valueField: 'id'
     ,data: [{"id":"255", "name":"charles"}
           , {"id":"261", "name":"rahman"}
           , {"id":"274", "name":"siva"}
           ]
}); 
tags.setValue(["255","261","274"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even you can do like this

```
  $('#ms-ajaxConfig').magicSuggest({
    data : [{
        "id": 255,
        "name": "charles"
    }, {
        "id": 261,
        "name": "rahman"
    }, {
        "id": 274,
        "name": "siva"
    }],
    valueField : id,
    value : [255,261,274]
});
```